# Woocommerce php code get_price_html()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WordPress and WooCommerce, I believe I have identified the line of code that is producing the output I want changed.

I am using free [artificer](https://woocommerce.com/products/artificer/) theme from WooCommerce and the index.php has a line:

```
<h3>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <span class="price">
        <?php echo $_product->get_price_html(); ?>
    </span>
</h3>
```

This produces something like "Black Stone - $43" (i.e. *product title - price*)

I want something like "Black Stone 
 $43"
(i.e. *product title `<br/>` price*)

It looks like there are some filters for the ``get_price_html()` function, but the documentation is not very good or I just don't understand how to navigate through it.

Any direction would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/how-to-edit-the-get-price-html-on-woocommerce

Comment: try `$_product->get_price();`

Comment: if you just want to remove `-` you do it by pure php using str_replace

Comment: I figured out that <h3><?php the_title(); ?> <span class="price"></span></h3> still produces the - so it must be coming in from a hook or something.

Answer (score 14):

all the `$product->get_price_html();`
produces something like this:

```
<del><span class="amount">£8.00</span>–<span class="amount">£9.00</span></del>
<ins><span class="amount">£7.00</span>–<span class="amount">£8.00</span></ins>
```

to manipulate this data, you must extract it from this string

If you use WP filters - you will change `get_price_html()` output everywhere and if you need to change `get_price_html()` output just in one place, you should do next:

```
global $product;

$price_html = $product->get_price_html();

$price_html_array = price_array($price_html);

function price_array($price){
    $del = array('<span class="amount">', '</span>','<del>','<ins>');
    $price = str_replace($del, '', $price);
    $price = str_replace('</del>', '|', $price);
    $price = str_replace('</ins>', '|', $price);
    $price_arr = explode('|', $price);
    $price_arr = array_filter($price_arr);
    return $price_arr;
}
```

now you have same data in array

```
Array ( [0] => £8.00–£9.00 [1] => £7.00–£8.00 )
```

and you can do with it everything you want

to apply global filter, you must add

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_array', 100, 2 );
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the filter you're looking for:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $price = '';
    $price .= woocommerce_price($product->min_variation_price);
    return $price;
}
```

This just changes it so that the min price is displayed (and nothing else) as it's not clear how you want to format/style it. You can access various other details via the $product object to customise the output. Use it within your functions.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by modifying the said line and adding a small css code in theme `custom.css` file.

Replace the given code by this:

```
<h3>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <br/>
    <span class="price">
        <?php echo $_product->get_price_html(); ?>
    </span>
</h3>
```

And add the following css code either in `custom.css` (recommended) file or in last line of theme `style.css` file.

```
ul.featured-products li h3 .price::before{
    content : '' !important;
}
```

*Please Note: The above code is tested and working fine with Artificer version 1.3.16 (which was released on 05 May, 2016.)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: What file has the function get_price_html()?

Answer (score 0):

I made this function based in source code.

```php
function extractPrices($product, $currency = "BRL") 
  {
    if($product->is_type( 'simple' )) {
      return (object) ["regular_price" => $product->regular_price, "sale_price" => $product->sale_price];
    }

    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    if (!empty( $prices['price'])) {
      $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
      $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
      $min_reg_price = current( $prices['regular_price'] );
      $max_reg_price = end( $prices['regular_price'] );

      if ( $min_price !== $max_price ) {

          return (object) ["regular_price" => $max_price, "sale_price" => $min_price];

      } elseif ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price === $max_reg_price ) {

          return (object) ["regular_price" => $max_reg_price, "sale_price" => $min_price];
     
      } else {

          return (object) ["regular_price" => $max_price, "sale_price" => $min_price];
    
      }
    }
    
    return (object) ["regular_price" => null, "sale_price" => null];

  }
```

And another function to get off discount

```php
 function calculeOff($prices): ?int 
  {
    if(!empty($prices->sale_price) && !empty($prices->regular_price)) {
      return round(100 - ($prices->sale_price / $prices->regular_price * 100));
    }
    return null;
  }
```