# Editing output <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm trying to edit the html output of the code

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

I need to separate the regular price and the promo price in separate siblings divs. And then calculate the price difference between then and show it how much its the discount.

I've read all the questions here regarding this problem but nothing could help me. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346067/woocommerce-php-code-get-price-html) particular once came close.

Comment: why didn't it help you? what have you tried? so us some code and it's output

Comment: See this related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757920/display-the-discounted-percentage-near-sale-price-in-single-product-pages-for-wc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255535/how-to-display-the-regular-price-and-sale-price-in-single-product-and-loop-pages/47255937#47255937

Comment: @LoicTheAztec
 
Hello, almost there. 

just discovered that i need the variation price and the promotional variable price. This is a variable product.

Should i make another question/thread?

Comment: You should search a bit as this has been already answered too …

Comment: May be this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005952/woocommerce-variable-products-keep-only-min-price-with-a-custom-label/46009513#46009513

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i have made another questionar to clarify the problem. Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328965/displaying-price-only-when-the-variation-is-selected-and-discount-in-percentage