# Displaying price only when the variation is selected and discount in percentage relatively to the regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I've this problem. Let me show pictures so I can explain better.

Variation product selected but because all the variations have the same price the price do not show in the bottom:
[image: Variation product selected but because all the variations have the same price the price do not show in the bottom.]

Variation product selected, because they have different PROMO prices they show on top and the regular-promo price after selection:
[image: Variation product selected, because they have different PROMO prices they show on top and the regular-promo price after selection]

What I need is that only after selected the variations the price is show in the bottom like the second image and calculation the discount between the promo variation price and the regular variation price. I need the same behavior in the two cases.

I've searched a lot, but none of the things have solved this behavior. Here some answer that are very close:

- [calculating discount percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757920/display-the-discounted-percentage-near-sale-price-in-single-product-pages-for-wc)
- [variation prices customizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005952/woocommerce-variable-products-keep-only-min-price-with-a-custom-label/46009513#46009513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, there this simple dedicated filter hook **`woocommerce_show_variation_price`** that will make exactly what you are expecting:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', 'filter_show_variation_price', 10, 3 );
function filter_show_variation_price( $condition, $product, $variation ){
    if( $variation->get_price() === "" ) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and work… This will display the selected variation price even if all variations prices are the same…

Comment: Hello. Im very sorry for the delay in reporting about your help, i got a almost deadly flu.

So, its not working. How can i debug to see whats its going on?

And how about the discount percentage calculation only in the price after the variation is selected?

Comment: @zeYuri Happy comme back to life!… Here you are asking 2 questions in One… Kindly this is not the way on StackOverFlow. So for now my code displays the selected variation price even if all prices are the same for all variations (the 'woocommerce_show_variation_price' hook is dedicated to that in WooCommerce). For the discount percentage, that should be another question that you will ask on a new question and I will answer to it with pleasure. If the code doesn't work for you, I can't tell… For me it works as I always test my code before.

Comment: oh, got it. Yes this is working very nicely. thanks. i've made the other question. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530715/display-discount-percentage-after-variation-promo-price-is-selected