# Customize the selected product variation prices in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Essentially I am trying to figure out where variation data is calculated and displayed in the HTML when a user makes her selection. This is [my shop link](http://www.workwear.ur54.com/wp/product/helly-hansen-70335-alta-high-visibility-insulated-jacket/).

The specific Price I am referring to:

[image: Specific Price I am refering to]

Basically, I want to find out where this data is plugged in and where I can modify it.

That the data is imported by some JS in the template  `single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php`:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
    {{{ data.variation.price_html }}}
</div>
```

My end goal is to simply modify how the sale & price are displayed, maybe prefix them with something like **`Price:`** and **`Sale:`**.

WP Version: 4.9.1 
WC Version: 3.2.6 
Theme: Flatsome3 v3.3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following hooked function, you will ne able to prefix each price when product is on sale for all product types:

```
// Prefix the selected variation prices When discounted for variable products (on sale)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'prefix_variations_selected_prices', 10, 3 );
function prefix_variations_selected_prices( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    global $product;

    // Just for variable products on single product pages
    if( $product->is_type('variable') && is_product() ) {

        // Custom texts
        $price_txt =  __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ';
        $sale_txt = __(' Sale', 'woocommerce' ).': ';

        return '<del>' . $price_txt . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . $sale_txt . wc_price( $sale_price ) . '</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Based on this similar answer: 
[Display discount percentage after the selected variation sale price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530715/display-discount-percentage-after-the-selected-variation-sale-price-in-woocommer/47541918#47541918)

Comment: @gregbast1994 Glad it fit your need :)